# Find centroid using moments of all blobs

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, emgucv

im trying to find centroid of all contours in an image, but im only getting one centroid of the combined blobs. How do  find centroid using moments of all blobs?

This is my code:

```
_blobDetector.Detect(imginput, blobs1);
        blobs1.FilterByArea(100, int.MaxValue);

        float scale1 = (threshedimg.Width + threshedimg.Width) / 2.0f;
        _tracker.Update(blobs1, 0.01 * scale1, 5, 5);

        // Bitmap drawrect = new Bitmap(threshedimg.Bitmap);

        foreach (var pair1 in _tracker)
        {

            b1 = pair1.Value;

            Emgu.CV.Util.VectorOfVectorOfPoint contour = new Emgu.CV.Util.VectorOfVectorOfPoint();
            Mat heir2 = new Mat();
            CvInvoke.FindContours(imginput, contour, heir2, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.RetrType.External, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);


            for (int i = 0; i < contour.Size; i++)
            {
                moment = imginput.GetMoments(true);
                // CvInvoke.Moments(imginput, true);
                Point WeightedCentroid = new Point((int)(moment.M10 / moment.M00), (int)(moment.M01 / moment.M00));
                CvInvoke.Circle(imginputcolor, WeightedCentroid, 4, new MCvScalar(0, 255, 0), 5, LineType.EightConnected, 0);
                Point WeightedCentroidnew = WeightedCentroid;
                CvInvoke.Line(imginputcolor, WeightedCentroid, WeightedCentroidnew, new MCvScalar(255, 0, 0), 5, LineType.EightConnected, 0);

            }

   imageBox1.Image = imginputcolor;
```

This is the output im getting :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your **contour** is incorrect. Let you check it by some drawing to the image.

Comment: Hi, im getting the contour correctly. Just not displaying it here.